# iPhone stopwatch app to start by longitude and latitude position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nstimer, stopwatch

Is it possible to get this iphone app (http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_ios_stopwatch.php) to start and take the lap times based on Longitude and Latitude? So instead of having a start button when the phone goes past the GPS coordinates the timer starts and everytime it goes past the GPS coordinates it takes a lap time and stores it in the sql database.

Hope this makes sense...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. It might not have the precision you're looking for, but Core Location could do what you want pretty easily.

Create a `CLLocationManager`, then generate a `CLLocation` every so often. Call `distanceFromLocation` on the new `CLLocation` and the start location with some acceptable deviation. That should let you know when you pass your start area.

Here's an example of a header file for a class that implements location manager

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *startingPoint;

@end
```

Comment: Note:  You do not "just generate a CLLocation", you create a class that implements the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol, register as `CLLocationManager` delegate, and implement `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`